# Move a button/textbox position in my page programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have in my xaml code, 2 expander, into a border.
In each expander, I got a grid.

And in the grid, I got elements like button or textbox.

I want to put a button in the expander one, if the current user is register, and in the expander two, if the user is not register.

Copy only one expander, beacause they are fully similar.

```
<Border CornerRadius="0,0,10,10">
    <Border.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFBFBFB" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Background>
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.5" />
    </Border.Effect>

    <toolkit:Expander Height="auto" 
                      Width="auto"
                      Foreground="#FF100B49" 
                      IsExpanded="False" 
                      Name="expOne">
        <toolkit:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Orange"
                               FontSize="16" 
                               Text="Common informations" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:Expander.HeaderTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions  >
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Title"
                           Width="120"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Grid.Row="2"
                           Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </toolkit:Expander>
</Border>
```

Can I, programmatically, move a button into another expander/border?

Thank you.

Comment: you can all button/textbox, and display only object which must me shown, with property `Visibility`

Comment: That means that I have to double buttons, and code behind method to this buttons. Is there no other way?

Comment: not double code behind, as each component link to the same method.

Comment: @Zaphod There are other ways, but in my opinion Xaruth proposed you the easiest one. So why makes things more complicated for no reason?

Comment: @user2771704 Because I was'nt thinking it would accept that two different elements will link the same method.

Comment: @Xaruth Thank you. That works, I was thinking I had to double code behind, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make a complete answer (and not only a comment) :

you can all button/textbox, and display only object which must me shown, with property `Visibility`. Each component can link same method for action.

for exemple :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding FirstVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Click="Button_Click" Visibility="{Binding SecondVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Grid>
```

this is the easiest way, and probably the cleanier for your xaml.

Comment: That works perfectly fine, and indeed quite simple. Thanks Xaruth.